# How do I build SQLAlchemy relationships for performance?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I've built two models, `Message` and `EmailAddress` that are connected in a Many-to-Many relationship by the `MessageEmailAddress` table. (I used a `Model` class for `MessageEmailAddress` because there is associated metadata, `action`, with the relationship.) These `relationships` are all `lazy=dynamic`.

Running the instance method `Message.add_email_address()` is incredibly slow, approx. 1.5 secs per object!! The method it needs to check if there is a pre-existing relationship (i.e. row in `MessageEmailAddress`), and if not create a new one.

How do I build more performant relationships between the tables? What element of my code is causing such slow operation?

I've tried many other ways to create the Many-to-Many relationship with associated metadata - this is the only way that has not thrown errors.

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()


class Message(db.Model):
    """A single message."""
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    # Is there a way to dynamically create these?
    _email_addresses = relationship(
        "EmailAddress",
        secondary="message_email_address", lazy='dynamic', backref=backref("_messages", lazy='dynamic'))
    _email_addresses_from = relationship(
        "EmailAddress",
        primaryjoin="and_(Message.id==MessageEmailAddress.message_id, MessageEmailAddress.action=='from')",
        secondary="message_email_address",
        lazy='dynamic',
        backref=backref('_messages_from', lazy='dynamic')
    )
    _email_addresses_to = relationship(
        "EmailAddress",
        primaryjoin="and_(Message.id==MessageEmailAddress.message_id, MessageEmailAddress.action=='to')",
        secondary="message_email_address",
        lazy='dynamic',
        backref=backref('_messages_to', lazy='dynamic')
    )

    def add_email_address(self, email_str, action, name=None):
        """Setter method for all related EmailAddress objects.

        Args:
            email_str: A string, ex. "david@gmail.com"
            action: A string describing header action, ex. "from"
            name: Optional string for name of EmailAddress

        """
        # Ensure connection between Message, EmailAddress, and action is unique
        action_prop = '_email_addresses_' + action
        pre_existing = getattr(self, action_prop).filter_by(email_address=email_str).all()

        if pre_existing and len(pre_existing):
            return

        # Add new connection
        email_address = EmailAddress.get_or_create(
            email_address=email_str, create_kwargs=dict(name=name))
        a = MessageEmailAddress(message_id=self.id, email_id=email_address.id, action=action)
        db.session.add(a)
        db.session.commit()

        return email_address


class EmailAddress(db.Model, ModelMixin):
    """A single email address.

    Relationships to Message: _messages, _messages_from, _messages_to, etc.
    """
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...


class MessageEmailAddress(db.Model):
    # Join Message and EmailAddress tables
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    message_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('message.id'), nullable=False)
    email_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('email_address.id'), nullable=False)
    action = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)  # Ex. From, To, Bcc

    message = db.relationship("Message", backref=backref("message_email_address", lazy='dynamic'))
    email_address = db.relationship("EmailAddress", backref=backref("message_email_address", lazy='dynamic'))
```

Comment: You should ask your DBA and if you don't have one probably this aspect of the project is not important enough for you to worry about. I'm saying this because 1) there is too much cargo-cult database advice on the Internet, 2) Database performance is often counter-intuitive and 3) Most of the time index tuning is more important than crafting performance-wise perfect SQL statements.

Comment: It would be useful if you can provide the list of queries emitted by sqlalchemy and the time spent by each.